# wp query_posts returns no posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress template for displaying search results.
It works fine, but when i want to change sort order, I cannot.
query_posts doens't work as expected - it doesn't show any results.

Here is part of my code:

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' );
if (have_posts()) {
     theme_post_wrapper(
                array('content' => '<h4 class="box-title" >'. $count.'</h4>')
        );                                                          

            /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */
            if (theme_get_option('theme_top_posts_navigation')) {
                theme_page_navigation();
            }

            /* Start the Loop */
            while (have_posts()) {                    
                the_post();                        
                get_template_part('content', 'search');                                                 
            }

            /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */
            if (theme_get_option('theme_bottom_posts_navigation')) {
                theme_page_navigation();
            }

} else {
            //NO DATA FOUND
}
```

If I remove query_posts then results are displayed.
If I add query_posts as above then no data are displayed.
This is very strange and I have no idea what to do this.
How to debug? Is there a way to get something like SQL query? Something else?
Give me some ideas, please.

I have alsoo tried to add order or/and orderby parameters as GET parameters - nothing happened to search results (no sorting changed).

Comment: Just a side note, do you have `wp_reset_query();` at the end of your code? If not, make sure you add it!

Comment: begin by echo $query_string;